# How can I hide encrypted volumes from Unity users?

Tags: unity, mount, encryption, luks

Basically I want to make sure that users cannot mount or attempt to decrypt and mount local volumes. I figured for unencrypted volumes it is sufficient to create a noauto fstab entry that points to a path that cannot be accessed by any user for the volumes not to show in the file explorer anymore.

However, for (LUKS) encrypted volumes it seems to be a different story. Creating crypttab entries doesn't make a difference it seems. Only opened crypt volumes won't show up in the file explorer anymore.

How can I disable that encrypted volumes are shown to the users? Preferably not by configuring any per-user settings but globally.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this solution. Is not per user.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2198120